# How to group columns values and rank them in tsql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

Spend half an hour trying to format my question but failed terribly (WHY IS IT SO DAMN HARD!?), so instead I'm going to post a picture that explains everything quite simply.
[image]

Some explanation, I have a table that has a set of columns that repeat in a predictable pattern, I want to query that pattern (please look at the picture to understand).

I'm still an amateur with SQL Server (started less than a month ago) and don't know where to begin.

Comment: Could you give us more details about column3? It seems to me clear that the column2 is related to your ordering but not about the column3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK`:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0573/7/0)**

```
SELECT 
   row_number,
   [GROUP_NUMBER] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY column1, column2, column3),
   column1,
   column2,
   column3,
   random_value
FROM tab
ORDER BY Row_Number;
```

Comment: this one works perfectly, I'm going to have to take a look at SQL Server ranking functions if I ever want to pass 461. Thank you very much!